# Correctness of FIPS 186-4 square test algorithm

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, integers

[Federal Information Processing Standard 186-4 appendix C.4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=84) gives (without reference) an algorithm intended to test if a positive integer $C$ (which can be thousands bits) is a square:

1. Set $n$, such that $2^n>C\ge2^{(n-1)}$.
2. $m=\lceil n/2\rceil$.
3. $i=0$.
4. Select $X_0$, such that $2^m>X_0\ge2^{(m-1)}$.
5. Repeat
     5.1   $i=i+1$.
     5.2   $X_i=((X_{i-1})^2+C)/(2X_{i-1})$.
   Until $(X_i)^2<2^m+C$.
6. If $C=\lfloor X_i\rfloor^2$, then *status* = `PERFECT SQUARE`.
   Else *status* = `NOT A PERFECT SQUARE`.
7. Return *status*.

At step 5.2, can we compute $X_i$ by Euclidean division (that is rounding down to the nearest integer)? In the affirmative, how do we prove the algorithm terminates, and yields correct *status*, regardless of the choice made at step 4? Towards this, what invariant condition should we prove is maintained during step 5?

---

I observe that in step 6 it's used $\lfloor X_i\rfloor$ rather then just $X_i$, and that's strange if $X_i$ is intended to be an integer. Also, the [notes](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=85) after the statement of the algorithm, intended to prove it correct, seem written with real values in mind.

<sup>Remark: A practical implementation could suppress $i$ (thus steps 3 and 5.1), and use a single $X$ for all the $X_i$. It could use an arbitrary integer type or class for at least $C$ and $X$.</sup>

Comment: Conclusion: it directly follows from the accepted [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/156859/2325) that yes we can and should use Euclidean division to compute $X_i$ at step 5.2, and use $X_i$ where there is $\lfloor X_i\rfloor$ at step 6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is more or less [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) applied to the function $f:x\to x^2 - C$. The algorithm finds $r = \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$ and check whether $r^2 = C$ or not.

If we define $g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x - \frac{x^2-C}{2x} = \frac{x^2+C}{2x}$, then the computed sequence is $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{k+1} = \left\lfloor g(x_k)\right\rfloor$.

Assume $x_k > \sqrt{C}$ for some $k$. Then:
$$x_{k+1}=\left\lfloor g(x_k)\right\rfloor\leqslant g(x_k) = \dfrac{x_k^2+C}{2x_k}<\frac{2x_k^2}{2x_k} = x_k$$

But since $x_0 >0$, let us distinguish:

- if $x_0 < \sqrt{C}$, then $2x_0(g(x_0) - \sqrt{C}) = x_0^2 + C -2\sqrt{C}x_0 = (x_0 -\sqrt{C})^2 > 0$. That means that $g(x_0)> \sqrt{C}$ and that $x_1 \geqslant \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$;
- otherwise $x_0 \geqslant \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$.

With the previous properties, we conclude that there exists $k>0$ such that $x_k \leqslant \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$ (otherwise $(x_k)_{k>0}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence with $\left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$ as a lower bound).

Let $k$ be the first integer $>0$ such that $x_k \leqslant \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$. That means that $g(x_{k-1}) > \sqrt{C}$. Since $x_k = \left\lfloor g(x_{k-1})\right\rfloor \leqslant \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$, we conclude that $x_k = \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$.

Since (as stated in your document), $x_k^2 < 2^m +C$ implies $x_k-\sqrt{C}<1$, that means that $x_k \leqslant \left\lfloor \sqrt{C}\right\rfloor$ so we conclude on the termination and the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: I like the answer's approach of viewing the algorithm as finding the zero of $f$ by Newton's method (that is by iterating $g$), except for rounding down to the nearest integer at each step.